# Is this correctly CFG for this language?

Tags: context-free-grammar

$$
L = \{ a^{2n}w \mid |w| = n\},\ \Sigma=\{ a,b \}
$$

My CFG:
$$
S \to \epsilon\mid aaST \\
T\to a \mid b
$$

My lecturer wrote this is wrong because $w$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: Can $n$ be $0$?

Comment: Yes, there is no limit on n.

Comment: Your lecturer is wrong and you are correct, assuming $S$ is the start symbol.

Comment: So $w$ is any combination ob $a$ and $b$ of legth $n$?  If so, maybe the lecturer is confused that words like $aaaaab\in L$?

Comment: Yea I think so. I am afraid to appeal 